# Python: Is it possible to make this tail-recursion factorial even faster?

Tags: python, performance, recursion, combinatorics, tail-recursion

I'm making a utilities class for an application which involves combinatorics.

I've made two factorial funcion which tail recursion. The second one improves a lot the performance when coming to calculate combinatorics numbers (I think in English they are called **n choose k**, I use C(n,k) notation and made a nCk function also).

So I measured times, and I achieved my goal. My new combinatorics functions are much faster than the new ones.

But when coming to the factorial function I found that my new factorial function 'f' is a bit slower than the first one 'fact'.

Is there a way to make this 'f' function as good in performance as 'fact'?

You can see the main test execution and results in my machine at the bottom.

**Source code**

```
class Utils(object):
    """
    Class with useful functions
    """

    @staticmethod
    def fact(i, _current_factorial=1):
        '''
        The factorial function
        :param i: the number for calculating the factorial
        :param _current_factorial: for internal use, it is the acumulated product
        :return the result
        '''
        if i == 1:
            return _current_factorial
        else:
            return Utils.fact(i - 1, _current_factorial * i)

    @staticmethod
    def f(i, k=None, _current_factorial=1):
        '''
        The factorial function
        If k is given, it calculates the factorial but only with
        the k-th first numbers.
        Example:
            f(6) = 6 · 5 · 4 · 3 · 2 · 1
            f(6, 2) = 6 · 5
            f(6, 3) = 6 · 5 · 4
            f(9, 4) = 9 · 8 · 7 · 6
        :param i: the number for calculating the factorial
        :param k: optional, the number for calculating the factorial
        :param _current_factorial: for internal use, it is the acumulated product
        :return the result
        '''
        if k is None:
            k = i
        if i == 1 or k == 0:
            return _current_factorial
        else:
            return Utils.f(i - 1, k - 1, _current_factorial=_current_factorial * i)

    @staticmethod
    def C(n, k=1):
        '''
        Statistical combinations 'nCk'
        :param n: number of elements to be combined
        :param k: number of elements to be taken for each combination
        :return: the 'n choose k' mathematical result
        '''
        return Utils.fact(n) / (Utils.fact(k) * Utils.fact(n - k))

    @staticmethod
    def nCk(n, k=1):
        '''
        Statistical combinations 'nCk'
        :param n: number of elements to be combined
        :param k: number of elements to be taken for each combination
        :return: the 'n choose k' mathematical result
        '''
        return Utils.f(n, k) / Utils.f(k)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    NUM_TEST_ITERATIONS = 7500
    MAX_NUMBER_WITHOUT_STACKOVERFLOW = 998

    import time

    start = time.process_time()
    for i in range(NUM_TEST_ITERATIONS): Utils.f(MAX_NUMBER_WITHOUT_STACKOVERFLOW)
    elapsed = time.process_time() - start
    print('Function {} took {} to get result {}'.format('f', elapsed, Utils.f(MAX_NUMBER_WITHOUT_STACKOVERFLOW)))

    start = time.process_time()
    for i in range(NUM_TEST_ITERATIONS): Utils.fact(MAX_NUMBER_WITHOUT_STACKOVERFLOW)
    elapsed = time.process_time() - start
    print('Function {} took {} to get result {}'.format('fact', elapsed, Utils.fact(MAX_NUMBER_WITHOUT_STACKOVERFLOW)))

    start = time.process_time()
    for i in range(NUM_TEST_ITERATIONS): Utils.nCk(997, 4)
    elapsed = time.process_time() - start
    print('Function {} took {} to get result {}'.format('nCk', elapsed, Utils.nCk(997, 4)))

    start = time.process_time()
    for i in range(NUM_TEST_ITERATIONS): Utils.C(997, 4)
    elapsed = time.process_time() - start
    print('Function {} took {} to get result {}'.format('C', elapsed, Utils.C(997, 4)))
```

**On screen**:

```
Function f    took 7.854962716 to get result 402790050127220994538240674597601587306681545756471103647447357787726238637266286878923131618587992793273261872069265323955622495490298857759082912582527118115540044131204964883707335062250983503282788739735011132006982444941985587005283378024520811868262149587473961298417598644470253901751728741217850740576532267700213398722681144219777186300562980454804151705133780356968636433830499319610818197341194914502752560687555393768328059805942027406941465687273867068997087966263572003396240643925156715326363340141498803019187935545221092440752778256846166934103235684110346477890399179387387649332483510852680658363147783651821986351375529220618900164975188281042287183543472177292257232652561904125692525097177999332518635447000616452999984030739715318219169707323799647375797687367013258203364129482891089991376819307292252205524626349705261864003453853589870620758596211518646408335184218571196396412300835983314926628732700876798309217005024417595709904449706930796337798861753941902125964936412501007284147114260935633196107341423863071231385166055949914432695939611227990169338248027939843597628903525815803809004448863145157344706452445088044626373001304259830129153477630812429640105937974761667785045203987508259776060285826091261745049275419393680613675366264232715305430889216384611069135662432391043725998805881663054913091981633842006354699525518784828195856033032645477338126512662942408363494651203239333321502114252811411713148843370594801145777575035630312885989779863888320759224882127141544366251503974910100721650673810303577074640154112833393047276025799811224571534249672518380758145683914398263952929391318702517417558325636082722982882372594816582486826728614633199726211273072775131325222240100140952842572490801822994224069971613534603487874996852498623584383106014533830650022411053668508165547838962087111297947300444414551980512439088964301520461155436870989509667681805149977993044444138428582065142787356455528681114392680950815418208072393532616122339434437034424287842119316058881129887474239992336556764337968538036861949918847009763612475872782742568849805927378373244946190707168428807837146267156243185213724364546701100557714520462335084082176431173346929330394071476071813598759588818954312394234331327700224455015871775476100371615031940945098788894828812648426365776746774528000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Function fact took 6.757415364 to get result 402790050127220994538240674597601587306681545756471103647447357787726238637266286878923131618587992793273261872069265323955622495490298857759082912582527118115540044131204964883707335062250983503282788739735011132006982444941985587005283378024520811868262149587473961298417598644470253901751728741217850740576532267700213398722681144219777186300562980454804151705133780356968636433830499319610818197341194914502752560687555393768328059805942027406941465687273867068997087966263572003396240643925156715326363340141498803019187935545221092440752778256846166934103235684110346477890399179387387649332483510852680658363147783651821986351375529220618900164975188281042287183543472177292257232652561904125692525097177999332518635447000616452999984030739715318219169707323799647375797687367013258203364129482891089991376819307292252205524626349705261864003453853589870620758596211518646408335184218571196396412300835983314926628732700876798309217005024417595709904449706930796337798861753941902125964936412501007284147114260935633196107341423863071231385166055949914432695939611227990169338248027939843597628903525815803809004448863145157344706452445088044626373001304259830129153477630812429640105937974761667785045203987508259776060285826091261745049275419393680613675366264232715305430889216384611069135662432391043725998805881663054913091981633842006354699525518784828195856033032645477338126512662942408363494651203239333321502114252811411713148843370594801145777575035630312885989779863888320759224882127141544366251503974910100721650673810303577074640154112833393047276025799811224571534249672518380758145683914398263952929391318702517417558325636082722982882372594816582486826728614633199726211273072775131325222240100140952842572490801822994224069971613534603487874996852498623584383106014533830650022411053668508165547838962087111297947300444414551980512439088964301520461155436870989509667681805149977993044444138428582065142787356455528681114392680950815418208072393532616122339434437034424287842119316058881129887474239992336556764337968538036861949918847009763612475872782742568849805927378373244946190707168428807837146267156243185213724364546701100557714520462335084082176431173346929330394071476071813598759588818954312394234331327700224455015871775476100371615031940945098788894828812648426365776746774528000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Function nCk took 0.021283503999999454 to get result 40921610765.0
Function C   took 13.261998684000002   to get result 40921610765.0
```

Comment: Why not simply `math.factorial`? Presumably it uses optimized code. There are also `numpy` approaches/implementations to these functions. Reinventing the wheel typically isn't optimal. For one thing -- there isn't much of a point to calculate large factorials just to divide them away. The naïve approach to `nCk` does much more computation than it should.

Comment: Python doesn't do tail call elimination. There's no reason to expect tail recursion to be faster. (Also, this isn't Java; you don't need to stick all your utility functions in a class.)

Comment: Yes, the fastest way will probably be to use `math.factorial`. But if you really want to roll your own, don't stick your function in a class, and don't use recursion. Make a module-level function that uses the naive iterative approach. It will be much faster per-call. A hint: in Python, if you have a class with a bunch of `@staticmethod` decorated methods, and nothing else, then it shouldn't be a class. It should be a bunch of module-level functions.

Comment: @user2357112 is right, putting functions into a class just to group them together isn't necessary or commonly done in Python. If you just want to put them in a common namespace you can use a Module.

Comment: @user2357112 Making this iterative wouldn't cause an easy stackoverflow error? I tested numbers as you can deduce from my code, and numbers greater than 998 cause an error. About the functions in a single class, I know, but I like organization in this way, although it could be a module

Comment: @madtyn not only that, but the iterative approach will be faster. There is a significant overhead to function calls in Python, making equivalent recursive implementations generally slower than an iterative one. Using methods, i.e. anything with dotted attribute access, has an *even bigger overhead*.

Comment: @madtyn No, making this iterative would **not** cause an easy stackoverflow error, *quite the opposite*.

Comment: `math.factorial` can handle numbers much larger than 998. For example, it takes it less than a second to compute all 213,327 digits of 50,000!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok. You have convinced me change the class for a module and also for using math.factorial

Comment: Should I also change my nCk function?????

Comment: @madtyn change it to use `math.factorial`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In the denominator I'm changing it, but in the numerator is not much more work? Maybe I should do a list slice with a numpy product over them like `prod(list(range(k,0,-1))[:k])`

Comment: Or better: `prod(list(range(n,n-k,-1)))`

Comment: Don't use a `numpy.product` unless you are using `numpy` data-structures. At least, my suspicion would be that it would be slower than any naive implementation you might do, so, for example `from functools import reduce, from operator import mul, reduce(mul, range(k, n-k, -1))`. But, you can time it if you'd like. The performance gains you will get from simply using `math.factorial` are going to dwarf anything else.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes. It is incredible! I'm making benchmark testing and it looks great. You may post the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Rather, I think you should post your results and accept the answer, it is totally fine to write answers to your own questions. I think you have to keep it open for some set period of time before you accept, but it is reasonable, and you can synthesize everything you've done. I actually think this is a good example of where the performance considerations from Java lead you astray in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally removed the class code and used math.factorial, but I imported it with 'fact' name.

I also use a shortcut in the formula explained in the source code docs

This is much much better than the original. Thanks

**Source code** (omitting the main for brevity):

```
# Importing math.factorial with shorter name
from math import factorial as fact
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul


def C(n, k=1):
    '''
    Statistical combinations 'nCk'
    :param n: number of elements to be combined
    :param k: number of elements to be taken for each combination
    :return: the 'n choose k' mathematical result
    '''
    '''
        Original formula: fact(n) / (fact(k) * fact(n-k))

        Performance shortcut (about 40% faster): 
            1.- Calculates the numerator as the product over the first k-th elements of fact(n)
            Let's call this f'(n,k), we store it in fnkProduct variable
            Example:
                n = 6, k = 2 => f'(n,k) =   30 = 6 · 5
                n = 6, k = 3 => f'(n,k) =  120 = 6 · 5 · 4
                n = 9, k = 4 => f'(n,k) = 3024 = 9 · 8 · 7 · 6
            2.- Then divide it by fact(k)

        New formula: f'(n,k) / fact(k)

        '''
    # C(n,k) == C(n,n-k), but the second is best when k is much bigger
    k = n - k if k > (n // 2) else k
    fnkProduct = reduce(mul, range(n, n - k, -1), 1)
    return fnkProduct // fact(k)
```

**On screen** (this is the last comparison I did before I decided 15 million iterations)

```
Function C took 0.01638609299999999 to get result 40921610765.0
Function nCk took 0.016534930000000003 to get result 40921610765.0
```

Comment: Nice (+1). A couple of remarks: 1) `nCk = nC(n-k)` When `k > n/2` you will get better performance when you replace `k` by `n-k`. 2) `nCk` is always an integer but your current approach would returns a float. You might want to replace `/` by integer division `//`.

Comment: I did both. Thanks!